# What is Robust in java

Tags: java

I know that **Robust** is a Feature of java programming language. But I don't know what is the exact meaning of it and how to any programmer benefited by it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic adjective that means different things for different people. There's no measure of robustness, so you can't say "this language is more robust than that".

It might be used to differentiate a language from a "toy" language, that isn't meant for general purpose programming, but you aren't going to find any clear definitions, because there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Robust simply means heavy and strong and Java has a lot of facilities for programmers such as memory management, security features, networking features etc.

For details regarding exact meaning of feature "Robust", you can follow this link https://www.javatpoint.com/features-of-java